# Get names of a vector in a vector inside a for loop

Tags: r

I am applying k Nearest Neighbors (k-NN) function to a set of data for different values of k. 
I want to produce a document that is as much dynamic as possible, so that it can be easily used for other data and other values of k.

I am applying the knn function in a for loop for different values of k, and storing the results in variables named according to k (I show the code below).

The problem comes when I want to repeat that pattern of code and use the outputs of the knn function to retrieve the probabilities and also give a name according to k when I run the for loop.

The data:

- `data_train` and `data_test` are data frames with the following structure:

  ```
    v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
  1  1  0  1  0  1
  2  0  1  1  0  1
  3  1  1  1  1  1
  4  0  1  1  0  0
  5  1  0  1  0  1
  ```
- `train lab` is a factor: `"+" "+" "-" "-" "-"`

This is the code that is working for applying the `knn()` function:

```
# Using function knn() from class
# the values in ks must have been defined at the top of the document
ks = c(3, 5, 7)


test_pred_names = c()

for (k in ks){

     # Assigning different variable names according to kc
     test_pred<-paste("test_pred_", k, sep = "")

     # Including the argument prob=TRUE outputs the probabilities of     the predicted class together with the predicted class for each test case

     # Assigning the test_pred name to the output of knn
     print(assign(test_pred, knn(train=data_train, test=data_test,     cl=train_lab, k, prob = TRUE)))

     # Storing the names of the variables for each knn output
     test_pred_names = c(test_pred_names, test_pred)
}

# Storing the outputs of knn in a vector under the names defined in test_pred_names
test_preds <-mget(test_pred_names, envir = globalenv())
```

Then, I use the results in `test_preds` to get a vector with only a part of the output from `knn`, the probabilities:

```
test_prob_names = c()

# Extracting the probabilities for each of the outputs of knn
for (test_pred in test_preds){

      # assign different variable names according to k
      print(a = names(test_pred)) # this returns NULL

      # Assigning the test_prob name to the output of attr
      print(test_prob<-paste("prob_",a, sep = "")) # this returns "prob_"

      print(assign(test_prob, attr(test_pred, "prob")))
      test_prob_names = c(test_prob_names, test_prob)
}
```

Expected result:

```
test_prob_names
> "prob_test_pred_3", "prob_test_pred_5", "prob_test_pred_7"
```

Actual result: 
I get the desired output (the probabilities), but not the names of the variables.

```
test_pred_names
> "test_pred_3", "test_pred_5", "test_pred_7"

test_prob_names
> "prob_", "prob_", "prob_"
```

If I just run this, outside the loop:

```
names(test_preds)
> "test_pred_3", "test_pred_5", "test_pred_7"
```

(Other comment: I would actually prefer to cut the names and use only the number in "test_pred_5", so that the variable names are "test_prob_5" like, but this was my first approach).

Comment: you should add a sample of your data

Comment: When you use `mget`, you end up with a nice `list`. Why use `assign` to create individual objects and then use `mget` when it would be easier to put them in a `list` from the start?

Comment: You're entire first loop + `mget` is equivalent to `test_preds = lapply(ks, function(k) {knn(train=data_train, test=data_test, cl=train_lab, k, prob = TRUE)}; names(test_preds) = paste0("test_pred_", k)`

Comment: @Gregor Brilliant! I modified the whole two pieces of code like this:

```test_preds = lapply(ks, function(k) {knn(train=data_train, test=data_test, cl=train_lab, k, prob = TRUE)})```
 ```names(test_preds) = lapply(ks, function(k) {paste0("test_pred_", k)})```

```test_probs = lapply(test_preds, function(test_pred) {attr(test_pred, "prob")})```
```names(test_probs) = lapply(ks, function(k) {paste0("test_prob_", k)})```

Comment: You don't need to `lapply` on vectorized functions like `paste`. `names(test_preds) = paste0("test_pred_", k)` works just fine without `lapply` (and similarly for `names(test_probs)`.

Comment: And you don't need anonymous functions when you are iterating directly on the first argument. `lapply(test_preds, attr, "prob")` is a cleaner way to write `lapply(test_preds, function(test_pred) {attr(test_pred, "prob")})`. You only need the `function(k) {...}` business if you are using `k` for something other than the first arg.

Comment: @Gregor If I just use ```names(test_preds) = paste0("test_pred_", k)``` I get just the first vector named with the last value of k ```$test_pred_7``` and the other vectors ```$<NA>```

Comment: Sorry, should be `ks`, your full vector, not just `k`. `paste0("test_pred_", ks)`

Comment: @Gregor That works! Thank you for offering this clear solution